# Некорректное отображение строки в терминале

Tags: c++, c++11

Написал функцию которая возвращает только уникальные символы строки. Когда пытаюсь вывести в терминал – показывает какую-то дичь. Можете подсказать чо не так?

Я в C++ дня 4 от силы, и если функция полностью кривая то так и скажите.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>


std::string *get_unique(std::string *str){
    const int str_size = (str->size()) - 1;
    std::string unique_str;    
    std::set<char> unique_set;
    for (int i = 0; i < str_size; i++){        
        unique_set.emplace((*str)[i]);
    }
    const int unique_set_size = unique_set.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < unique_set_size - 1; i++){
        unique_str += *std::next(unique_set.begin(),i);      
    }
    std::string *punique_str = &unique_str;
    return punique_str;
}

int main(){
    std::string hello = "Hello, World";
    std::cout << *get_unique(&hello);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да, кривая. unique_str будет уничтожена при выходе из функции, а вы возвращаете на нее указатель. Вам не нужно возвращать указатель, просто верните объект строки.

Comment: Странно, вроде читал что можно вернуть локальный. `static` в этом как-то замешан?) Спасибо!

Comment: Croessmah, спасибо, понял.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кроме того, что нельзя возвращать указатель на локальные переменные, вы выбрали несколько сложноватый путь решения своей задачи. Вот так будет попроще:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

string get_unique(const string& str)
{
    string res = str;
    sort(res.begin(),res.end());
    res.erase(unique(res.begin(),res.end()),res.end());
    return res;
}

int main(){
    string hello = "Hello, World";
    cout << get_unique(hello);
}
```